# How to change last table's <tr> border color

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have a basic table with some rows. Each row has a border-bottom of 2px, but I would like the last  not to have any bottom at all. However, I do not seem to manage to do this with my current code.

```
<table id="products">
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="productsBottom"></tr>
</table>
```

This is my CSS:

```
#products tr {
    height: 94px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
}

tr.productsBottom {
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

Any help on this? I don't seem to understand why it works when I add a background-color, but changing the border in any way doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: i am wondering how your code is working. Because you have given border for table row. Only table columns will accept the border styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `border-bottom` to 'none', you can also select the last row directly without needing to assign it a class, using the `:last-child` selector

```
#products tr:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

You may also want to add:

```
#products{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: Or `border-bottom-width: 0;` or `border-bottom-color: transparent;`…

Comment: I cannot believe I spent so much time over this... thank you so much!

Comment: You may want to say this is using `CSS3` so there will be compatibility issues with older browsers.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for noticing! (And about the border-collapse, I already added this in some reset CSS, but thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

The first selector in your css has greater [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), hence it'll override the second one were you're setting the border to zero.

You can avoid this by using `!important` keyword or a more specific selector like

```
#products tr.productsBottom {
   border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

Comment: I only noticed now as I'm making this design for someone who already did part of the code. I usually use classes, not ID's so that's why I was stupid enough not to notice.

Answer (score 1):

This is down to [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).  The `#products tr` selector is most specific, so is the one that is applied.  To increase the specificity of the later selecter use:

```
#products tr.productsBottom {
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
}
```

Comment: May i know whai is the difference between [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23610816/2333214) and this?